# Get intent value Using getIntent() in MVVM repository

Tags: android, android-intent, mvvm, retrofit

I am giving the first steps in **MVVM**, I have a imbd app using retrofit. 
At this moment I have a dynamic URL that change the list of movies by passing a different movie **id**

```
@GET("3/movie/{movie_id}}/similar?api_key="+api_key+"&language=en-US&page=1")
Call<Similar> getAllSimilarMovies(@Path("movie_id") int movieId);
```

I have a Repository where I am trying to get the Intent values but the .getIntent doesn't work, the Intent is in the recyclerview passing the **ID** of the **movie clicked**

```
public class DetailsMovieRepository {

    private List<ResultSimilar> similarMoviesList;

    private MutableLiveData<List<ResultSimilar>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MutableLiveData<List<ResultSimilar>> getSimilarMutableliveData() {


        MovieDataService movieDataService = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();

        Intent intent = getIntent(); // DONT WORK!
         int movieId = intent.getIntExtra("movie_id",0);



        Call<Similar> call = movieDataService.getAllSimilarMovies(movieId);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Similar>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Similar> call, Response<Similar> response) {
                Similar similar = response.body();

                if (similar != null && similar.getResults() != null) {

                    similarMoviesList = similar.getResults();

                    mutableLiveData.setValue(similarMoviesList);



                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Similar> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.e("onFailed", "  ******" + t.getMessage() + "*******");


            }
        });

        return mutableLiveData;

    }


}
```

The question is how can I get the value from the Intent save as a var and pass here

```
Call<Similar> call = movieDataService.getAllSimilarMovies(---MY INTENT VALUE---);
```

Starting Intent in Adapter

```
       private SimilarViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            movieNameTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_movie_tv);
            movieRatingTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating_movie_tv);
            moviePosterIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster_iv);
            movieDateTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_movie_tv);
            movieVotesTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.votes_movie_tv);
            movieOriginalTitleTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.original_title_tv);
            movieLanguageTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.language_movie_tv);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    ResultSimilar selectedMovie = similarMoviesList.get(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("movie_id",selectedMovie.getId());
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                    Log.e("ddddd" , "***" + selectedMovie.getId());


                }});
        }
    }
```

Data service

```
public interface MovieDataService {



    String api_key = "5bbf68dcf3b4ad3875ef7b2ed5ddfe1a";

    @GET("3/movie/now_playing?api_key="+api_key+"&language=en-US&page=1")
    Call<Movies> getAllMovies();

    @GET("3/movie/{movie_id}}?api_key="+api_key+"&language=en-US")
        Call<MovieResponse> getMovieDetails(@Path("movie_id") int movieId) ;

    @GET("3/movie/{movie_id}}/similar?api_key="+api_key+"&language=en-US&page=1")
    Call<Similar> getAllSimilarMovies(@Path("movie_id") int movieId);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where you are sending the data via `intent`?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun I am sending or trying to, to the DetailsMovieRepository, that is here, but getIntent dosent work there!

Comment: If you are trying to send data to the `Repository` then pass it as a var. Post more code. Where `Call<Similar> call = movieDataService.getAllSimilarMovies(---MY INTENT VALUE---);` this code resides? Fragment/Activity?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun its a activity, that code is from the code above, what im trying to do is to save the data from the getExtra intent to a var and pass to ```Call<Similar> call = movieDataService.getAllSimilarMovies(---MY INTENT VALUE---)``` but when i use the .getIntent dosent work

Comment: Where is that code? Post it!

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun , i edit the main things, thank you for the help

Comment: Don't pass bundle. Use this `intent.putExtra("movie_id",selectedMovie.getId());"` Then read in the activity. using `.getIntExtra(movie_id);`.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun, thank you, but when i do ```Intent intent = getIntent(); ``` it doesn't work says that cant resolve method

Comment: Where are putting this method?? Put that in `DetailsActivity`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get data from `Intent` then you should do it in your `Activity` class, then you can pass it to you repository from the constructor for example `detailsMovieRepository(int id);`

Comment: `Repository` should follow the singleton pattern.